# Joomla4: Load a custom stylesheet (admin.css.php) in administration

Tags: joomla-4.x

I want my custom modules & custom template to fetch the parameter values (colors) from my custom template's backend. This way I can see what colors I'm picking when when I'm configuring my website.

That is, a button’s background color in the module/templates’s config page will match the color I defined in templateDetails.xml.

I have built a working J4 template and modules. In the **templateDetails.xml** I use the following

```
<description>My Custom Template
    <![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../media/vendor/mycustomfolder/admin.css.php" />]]>
</description>
```

Which allows me to add css for use in the backend. Later in **templateDetails.xml** there is a fieldset for defining colors:

```
<field name="color01" label="Color 01" type="color" format="hex" />
<field name="color02" label="Color 02" type="color" format="hex" />
<field name="color03" label="Color 02" type="color" format="hex" />
<field etc>
```

The **admin.css.php** file is supposed to access my custom template's color values using [this method](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23273/get-framework-and-template-params-in-joomla-4):

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__ . '/../../..');

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();
$container->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

$app                    = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
$defaultTemplate    = $app->getTemplate(true);
$params                     = $defaultTemplate->params;

header("Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate");
?>
.bg01 {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000; -webkit-text-fill-color:#fff; font-weight:bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color01'); ?>; }
.bg02 {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000; -webkit-text-fill-color:#fff; font-weight:bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color02'); ?>; }
.bg02 {-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000; -webkit-text-fill-color:#fff; font-weight:bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color02'); ?>; }
etc
```

So that in my custom modules and elsewhere in my custom template, when I have xml fields marked up with CSS classes like this:

```
<field name="backgroundColor" label="Background Color" type="radio" >
        <option class="btn bg01" value="color01">Color 01</option>
        <option class="btn bg02" value="color02">Color 02</option>
        <option class="btn bg03" value="color03">Color 03</option>
        etc
</field>
```

the **admin.css.php** should be fetching values for color01, color02, color03, (etc) and use them for the color attributes in .bg01, bg02, .bg03, etc.

So the fields in the backend of my custom templates should be using the classes .bg01, bg02, .bg03 etc, and the end result hould look like this

[image]

The problem is that the **templateDetails.xml** parameter values are not being passed through and the result is this:

[image]

When I inspect the admin page in Chrome I see this:

[image]

Clearly the **admin.css.php** is being accessed because the hardcoded values are being applied. But the variables (color values) are not.

My thought is that the php at the beginning of **admin.css.php** needs revision in order to properly fetch and pass the parameters from templateDetails.xml

I am hoping there is someone knowlegable enough about Joomla 4 to help me solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved for Joomla 4! I found this [tracker entry](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/34586) which lead me to update the php at the beginning of **admin.css.php**:

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__ . '/../../..');

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Boot the DI container.
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();
// UPDATED alias the session service key to the web session service.
$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

$app            = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
$myTemplate = $app->getTemplate(true);
$params         = $myTemplate->params;

header("Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate");
?>
```

Atum (the default admin template for Joomla 4) makes targeting the button backgrounds a little tricky. In order for backgrounds to work you must add the class **btn btn-outline-secondary** to your field options

```
<field name="backgroundColor" label="Background Color" type="radio" >
        <option class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg01" value="color01">Color 01</option>
        <option class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg02" value="color02">Color 02</option>
        <option class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg03" value="color03">Color 03</option>
        etc
</field>
```

And in the **admin.css.php**, use the following for each button:

```
.bg01 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color01'); ?>; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg01 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color:<?php echo $params->get('color01'); ?>; }
```

This will create two color states for when the button is selected, or not selected. Here is the result:

[image]

UPDATE: In order for this method to work, the template that is using

```
<![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../media/vendor/mycustomfolder/admin.css.php" />]]>
```

must be set as the default template otherwise the colors will not be displayed.

Comment: Great self-solve.  Please award your own answer the green tick to mark this page as resolved.