# Security concern in Joomla .php: is define('_JEXEC', 1) safe to use?

Tags: security, joomla-4.x

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398122/cannot-have-ajax-working-in-my-joomla-module#comment-18304045) on joomla.stackechange which has me concerned:

*"define('_JEXEC', 1) is a bad for security in the module. It allows people to use this file as an alternative entry point for joomla."*

I've created a **css.php** file as an adjunct to a custom Joomla 4 template. It uses **define('_JEXEC', 1)** to load some of the template's color parameters in the backend (a history of that can be found [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/31400/joomla4-load-a-custom-stylesheet-admin-css-php-in-administration/))

Can anyone tell me if this file is a security risk:

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__ . '/../../..');
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Boot the DI container.
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

// alias the session service key to the web session service.
$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

$app       = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
$template  = $app->getTemplate(true);
$params    = $template->params;

header("Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate");
?>
.bg01 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color01'); ?>; }
.bg02 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color02'); ?>; }
.bg03 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color03'); ?>; }
.bg04 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color:<?php echo $params->get('color04'); ?>; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg01 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color:<?php echo $params->get('color01'); ?>; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg02 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color:<?php echo $params->get('color02'); ?>; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg03 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color:<?php echo $params->get('color03'); ?>; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg04 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color:<?php echo $params->get('color04'); ?>; }
<!-- EOF -->
```

If I use a browser to navigate to the css.php file location, it displays only the CSS:

```
.bg01 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color: #9E9E9E; }
.bg02 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color: #607D8B; }
.bg03 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color: #3F51B5; }
.bg04 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; border-color: #495057; font-weight: bold; color: #2196F3; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg01 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color: #9E9E9E; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg02 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color: #607D8B; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg03 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color: #3F51B5; }
.btn-check:checked + .btn-outline-secondary.bg04 {text-shadow: 0px 1px #000000; color:#fff; background-color: #2196F3; }
```

Is this a vulnerability? Can anyone recommend an alternative method for retrieving (color) parameters in admin? I've seen [com_ajax](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) mentioned but I don't enough about it or whether it's appropriate to use in this case.

(Reference to a working example would be ideal as I am very much a novice when it comes to Joomla PHP -- being able to step through existing pieces of code has been my best learning tool)

Comment: Regarding the quoted comment, this was before Joomla had `com_ajax` and using Ajax in a module without your own custom component wasn't possible (if I rightly remember)

Answer (score 1):

Constant check is used to prevent script execution when PHP files are accessed directly (e.g. in the browser). In your case this isn't an issue since your is essentially a separate application. It's a valid entry point.

There is an issue of your script not being a valid Joomla web application. It doesn't go over the standard request cycle which could cause some issues here and there. For instance, by adding `Itemid[]` parameter to the URL we can invoke a PHP warning:

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty in **C:\laragon\www\joomla-cms\libraries\src\Menu\AbstractMenu.php** on line 148

If error reporting is disabled in Joomla, the warning won't appear. But the point is, some code may rely on application being executed properly.

> I've seen com_ajax mentioned but I don't enough about it or whether it's appropriate to use in this case.

`com_ajax` is generally the right way to do something like this in Joomla. There are some faster options like caching the generated stylesheet to file. But arguably the best option for your case is using inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Iam absolutely agree with u,
This the part of hijacking source.

```
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__ . '/../../..');
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.
```

Its not use the namespace pattern to load joomla library..

The constant is only prevent execution addional file from being a part of Joomla.
The benefits without that constant is additional file cannot load all class and function from Joomla.

**THE TWEAK**

Someone still can load all core Joomla if him required or include the structure folder of Joomla includes folder like ur example.

**PREVENT THIS TWEAK**

A webmaster should know about secure environment in him folder structure.
Inteads of use a default structure folder come with installations. You should move all core to secure environment, random named the important folder or move outside the public_html

Comment: If you know that your command of English is not strong, please ask an AI chatbot to improve the quality before posting.  I'm not sure that I understand your answer well enough to try to edit it.