# Joomla 4 - get module params in external php

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-4

In Joomla 3, I get module params with this code:

```
// Create the Application
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_dev');
$presetParams = new JRegistry($module->params);

$fontSize = $presetParams['fontSize'];
```

In Joomla 4, I start with this code:

```
// Boot the DI container.
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

// Alias the session service key to the web session service.
$container->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

// Get the application.
$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
```

but

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_dev');
```

stopped working.

How can I access module params from external php file using the Joomla framework?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what you mean by external php file? It may be something you can do with the new console package - tricky to set up but very good for cron jobs. Also, how do you distinguish between multiple module instances?

Comment: for template params there is already an answer
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23273/get-framework-and-template-params-in-joomla-4/23286#23286

unfortunately not yet for modules